# Modify quiz counter using js

Tags: javascript, html, counter, countdown

I am currently working on a quiz app.
Simple multi-choise quiz, it's working fine, questions appears, countdown starts.. finally the score is displayed.
Now I wanted to add some "boosters" for the player to enhance the game play so I started with "time booster" that have to allow adding extra time to the player, here is the counter class:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
var myCountdownTest = new Countdown({
  time: 60, 
  width:200, 
  height:80, 
  rangeHi:"minute"
 });
 </script>
```

So I've added a button called "Add time!"

```
<button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='time btn btn-success' type='button' >Add time!</button>
```

Let's say I want that once the button is clicked, the time counter gets +20 sec so I wrote:

```
$(document).on('click','.time',function() {
  myCountdownTest.time=myCountdownTest.time+20;  
});
```

But that didn't work, what I am missing here?
PS: I want that this button be clickable just one time so the player can use this booster once then the button is locked.

Comment: You say your code didn't work. What happened (please add this to your question)?

Comment: We could have to see the definition of `Countdown` and its prototype to know how to help you.

Comment: Nothing happens, when I click "Add time!" nothing happens.

Comment: I found the countdown.js here
http://jsfiddle.net/y34wr/1/

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a lot of accurate help here. The code you linked is minified and obfuscated via use of shortened variable names and there is no documentation. All you're going to get are guesses which *might* land on something which works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but I thing here:

```
$(document).on('click','.time',function(){
myCountdownTest.time=myCountdownTest.time+20;  
});
```

you are attatching the clik event to the whole document. Try to do the same but on the button instead:

```
$("#<?php echo $i; ?>").on('click','.time',function(){
myCountdownTest.time=myCountdownTest.time+20;  

$(this).unbind( "click" );
});
```

The unbind line unattach the clic event on the button and it is no longer clickable.

Comment: Actually, I think the original syntax is ok - the second parameter is the selector - just slightly less common pattern... https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

The return from `new Countdown` does not have a `time` property exposed, but rather it has a `bx.time` property. Maybe you can try...

```
$(document).on('click','.time',function(){
  myCountdownTest.bx.time=myCountdownTest.bx.time+20;  
});
```

I am not sure if this is exactly the correct approach, as I do not know the api for the library, but that should explain why it is not doing what you expect.

---

UPDATE: if there is no API for updating time after init...

A bit brutal, but you could try to re-initialise the object with updated time parameter...

```
$(document).on('click','.time',function(){
  myCountdownTest = new Countdown({
                            time: myCountdownTest.bx.time+20, 
                            width:200, 
                            height:80, 
                            rangeHi:"minute"
                            });
});
```

Comment: You might also consider `myCountdownTest.bx.time += 20;`

Comment: Perhaps the library has no API for changing parameters after initialisation.

Comment: Ok, let's forget about this library, is there any other clear js file that I can work with & make the functionality I want?
I'm still new to JS, any help appreciated!